# How do I populate the dropdown field with data from the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The Challenge I am facing is how to a populate the dropdown field with data from the database. I am using javascript to add the dropdown field to the form. This is how the form should works, when you click on the add button on the form, a new dropdown list field with a populated data from the database is added to the form. The problem now is how populate the dropdown list when it is added to the form. I am trying to achieve this with ajax and I need some help.

controller class

```
@GetMapping("/assignSubjects")
public String assignSubjects( Model model) {
    
    List<Subjects> listSubjects = (List<Subjects>) subjectService.listAllSubjects();
    List<Staff> listStaffs = staffService.listAllStaff();
    
    model.addAttribute("listSubjects", listSubjects);
    model.addAttribute("listsStaffs", listStaffs);
    return "academics/assign_subject";
}
```

```js
 
addNextDetailSection = () => {
    contextPath = "[[@{/}]]";
  
    htmlTeacherSubjectSection = `
    
    <div class="row mt-2" >
      <div class="col-1">
        <label class=" col-form-label">Teacher</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4"> 
        <select class="custom-select " id="teacherSubjectSelectOption">
            <option selected>Teacher</option>   
         </select>  
      </div>

      <div class="col-1">
        <label class=" col-form-label ml-4">Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <select class="custom-select form-select-sm "  name="selectSubject">
            <option selected>Teacher</option>
                
         </select>
             
      </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    `;
    
    
   requestURL = contextPath + "assignSubjects"
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: requestURL,
      
      success: function(data){
        
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $("#teacherSubjectSelectOption").append('<option value="' + value.name + '"></option>');
         });
      }
    });
    
    
    
    $("#divStaffSubject").append(htmlTeacherSubjectSection);
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <i class="fas fa-users fa-2x"> <span>Assign Subject</span></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-end">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary fas fa-plus"
                    onclick="addNextDetailSection()">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form >
        <div id="divStaffSubject">
            <div class="row" id="divStaffSubIndex0">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <label class=" col-form-label">Teacher</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <select class="custom-select " name="selectTeacher">
                        <option selected>Teacher</option>
                        <th:block th:each="subject : ${listSubjects}">
                            <option th:value="${subject.id}">[[${subject.name}]]</option>
                        </th:block>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-1">
                    <label class=" col-form-label ml-4">Subject</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <select class="form-select ">
                        <option selected>Teacher</option>
                        <th:block th:each="staff : ${listsStaffs}">
                            <option th:value="${staff.id}">[[${staff.fullName}]]</option>
                        </th:block>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
        </div>

    </form>


</div>
```

Comment: remove `<th:block th:each="subject : ${listSubjects}"><option th:value="${subject.id}">[[${subject.name}]]</option></th:block>` and add `id="teacherSubjectSelectOption"`

Comment: id="teacherSubjectSelectOption"  is in htmlTeacherSubjectSection that is the code that generate the dropdown field to be added to the form. And <th:block th:each="subject : ${listSubjects}"><option th:value="${subject.id}">[[${subject.name}]]</option></th:block> works well. The point is when I click on the add button another dropdown list field should be added through the javascript code thats is where the problem is.